# How can I get the content between "<div>" and "</div>" via python sgmllib or parser?

Tags: python, html

The HTML code is like this:

```html
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">

    <h1>head</h1>
    <ul class="jobpara">
    <li class="floatl"><span>time：</span>2013-08-13</li> 
        <li class="floatl"><span>place：</span>new york</li> 
        <li class="floatl"><span>source </span>www.goole.com</li> 
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the content which is between `<div>` and `</div>` via Python sgmllib or parser?

Comment: Also, `<br>` is not an ending tag, it's just declared as either `<br>` or `<br/>`. Do you perhaps mean `<div>` or `<ul>`? Take a look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ it might be what you're looking for (it can parse and gather blocks of data within given objects (such as what you are looking for)

Comment: sorry ，i modify the question,thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://some-website.com/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

build_form = {}

for input_field in soup.findAll('input'):
    if input_field['type'] in ('hidden', 'text', 'password', 'submit', 'image'):
        if input_field.has_attr('name'):
            value = ''
            if input_field.has_attr('value'):
                value=input_field['value']
            build_form[input_field['name']] = value

print build_form
```

This is an example of how to use beautifulsoup giving you "data within" an object or all the objects of a certain kind.

Comment: You shouldn't use BeautifulSoup. It's horrendously slow. lxml is nearly two full orders of magnitude faster for much the same interface. http://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0

Comment: Good point, i hate web-parsing all in all and the only few times i do parse HTML traffic i'm only interested in 1% of all the data a site has to offer and i usually write my own parser for it. I'll have a look at `lxml` myself tho for future references.